# How can a Perl script know its own memory footprint?

Tags: windows, linux, perl, macos, memory

I have a long running Perl script and I'd like to let it know (and report) how much memory it is using. I'd like to have this information both on Linux and Windows and if possible on Mac OS X as well.

Comment: I don't think that `Linux::Smaps` or `grep VmSize /proc/$$/status` work under Mac OS, since the rely on the `/proc` table.

Answer (score 7):

These Perl modules could help you:

- Windows: [Win32::Process::Memory](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-Process-Memory/)
- Linux(and maybe Mac OSX): [Linux::Smaps](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Linux-Smaps/)

Answer (score 5):

This will show you how:

http://perldoc.perl.org/Devel/Peek.html

Also, http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html

and, man pages for perldebug and perldebguts.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick and dirty and most of all CPAN-free method. It works on any OS that provides a /proc file system, that is Linux and Unix derivates, including Mac OS X, and also on Cygwin under Windows:

```
perl -e 'print qx{ grep VmSize /proc/$$/status };'
```